# Subset sequential times (chron) and aggregate them

Tags: r

I have large data sets of voltage readings. I wish to determine frequency of different time periods where voltage is above a threshold. Therefore with the subset of voltages (>=2V), I wish to compute the length of sequential periods where the voltage based on 1 second sampling intervals. See example data below:

```
library(chron)
volts=c(2,3,4,5,6,2,2,3,4,5,5,5)
t=chron(times=c("23:03:20", "23:03:21", "23:03:22", "23:03:23","23:03:24","23:03:25","04:01:50","04:01:51","04:01:52","04:01:53","04:01:54","04:01:55"))
data=data.frame(volts,"time"=t)
```

This example has two series of interest, one from 23:03:20 to 23:03:25, and one from 04:01:50 to 04:01:55.

I wish to compute the duration of these periods and mean voltages for vast quantities of data on the condition that there be 30 seconds between periods for them to be considered discrete. I suspect my answer may rest with zoo, I would welcome suggestions.

Comment: +1 for a clearly stated question.  It would have been nice if you had also told us what you'd tried ...

Comment: will there be multiple across-day transitions?  Should the difference between `23:59:59` and `00:00:02` be computed as 3 seconds, or (24 hours - 3 seconds) ?

Answer (score 2):

Using same names in output as @BenBolker:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(data)

dt[, time := as.ITime(time)] # easier to deal with

dt[, list(meanvolts = mean(volts), duration = time[.N] - time[1], n = .N),
     by = list(period = 1 + c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(time)) >= 30)))]
#   period meanvolts duration n
#1:      1  3.666667 00:00:05 6
#2:      2  4.000000 00:00:05 6
```

Comment: I haven't thought about it too carefully, but are you sure that `abs(diff(time))>=30` works correctly over day boundaries, e.g. between `23:59:59` and `00:00:02` ? (It works for the specified input, which has a bigger gap across the day boundary ...)

Comment: @BenBolker `endpoints` is faster than `cumsum` to create index but `data.table` is unbeatable for the rest of process(looping and binding)

Comment: @BenBolker good point. My solution will not work for another reason before using `endpoints`. Since I add `2013-07-30` to `time` to convert it to a POSIXct. I will get `2013-07-30 00:00:02`  and not as expected `2013-07-31 00:00:02`

Comment: @BenBolker depends on definition of "correctly", since the day is not specified, it's not clear whether that's a 3 second or a ~24h difference - this will assume that's a ~24h difference

Comment: Maybe the OP could clarify.  I assumed that these were supposed to be on successive days.

Comment: Really nice (fast) solution here. @ Ben: correct there are successive days; these are trials over 48 hrs. I'm currently trying to integrate the date into this.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more efficient solution with `zoo`, but how about:

Sample data (repeated for convenience)

```
library(chron)
dat <- data.frame(volts=c(2,3,4,5,6,2,2,3,4,5,5,5),
  time=chron(times=c("23:03:20", "23:03:21", "23:03:22", 
             "23:03:23","23:03:24","23:03:25",
              "04:01:50","04:01:51","04:01:52","04:01:53",
              "04:01:54","04:01:55")))
```

Analysis:

```
daysecs <- 3600*24
dd <- c(unclass(diff(dat$time))*daysecs)   ## difference in seconds
## classify jumps to new periods, including day boundaries 
## (I haven't tested this carefully!)
new_per <- !((dd>0 & dd<30) | (dd<0 & dd<(-daysecs+30))) 
dat$period <- 1+c(0,cumsum(new_per)) ## a fairly standard trick
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(period),summarise,
      meanvolts=mean(volts),
      duration=tail(time,1)-time[1],
      n=length(volts))
```

Results:

```
##   period meanvolts duration n
## 1      1  3.666667 00:00:05 6
## 2      2  4.000000 00:00:05 6
```

`plyr` in particular is not super-fast, but I would try this out on your data and see if it is acceptably fast before coming back and giving us a sense of how fast it has to be (either editing your question ("I have 6 million voltage measurements ...") or posting a new question that links to this one)

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution `xts` package. Generally we use `period.apply` function to deal with such time series process. Here Actually, I am only using `endpoints` to create splitter index ( each 30 seconds) then looping using classic `sapply`.

```
library(xts)
## creating the `xts` objects.
x.z <- xts(data$volts,
           as.POSIXct(strptime(data$time,format='%H:%M:%S')))

INDEX <- endpoints(x.z,'secs',30)
xx <- sapply(1:(length(INDEX) - 1), function(y) {
  x <- x.z[(INDEX[y] + 1):INDEX[y + 1]]
  data.frame(period=y,
             duration=diff(range(index(x))),
             mm = mean(x),
             len = length(x))
})


t(xx)
     period duration mm       len
[1,] 1      5        4        6  
[2,] 2      5        3.666667 6
```

**EDIT** How `endpoints` deal with the special case where time index is  over day boundaries?

Creating an example:

```
## creating xts object index
ii <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data$time,format='%H:%M:%S'))
## here I add  day to simulate day boundary
ii[6]  <- as.POSIXct(ii[6] + as.difftime(1,units='days'))
```

now my time serie looks like :

```
    x.z
                    [,1]
2013-07-31 04:01:50    2
2013-07-31 04:01:51    3
2013-07-31 04:01:52    4
2013-07-31 04:01:53    5
2013-07-31 04:01:54    5
2013-07-31 04:01:55    5
2013-07-31 23:59:55    2
2013-07-31 23:59:56    3
2013-07-31 23:59:57    4
2013-07-31 23:59:58    5
2013-07-31 23:59:59    6
2013-08-01 00:00:02    2   ## day boundaries here
```

Applying the same code (beginning of the solution) we get **3** periods and not **2 as expected**:

```
 t(xx)
     period duration mm len
[1,] 1      5        4  6  
[2,] 2      4        4  5  
[3,] 3      0        2  1    ## 2013-08-01 00:00:02    2
```